# my.cnf.d/server.cnf configuration - dash or underscore

Tags: mysql, mariadb, my.cnf

I'm using MySQL/MariaDB 10.0

In my server.cnf usually in the past I've used underscores for the majority of things in this configuration. I'm testing out a generated .cnf but it has dashes instead of underscores, do dashes work? example:

```
query-cache-type
query-cache-size
```

Usually I'd use _, will mysql accept and use these? I know SSL related is specific, but are these specific as well?

(note: I know there is a similar question to this but there was no real answer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL configuration: when to use hyphen and when to use underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736395/mysql-configuration-when-to-use-hyphen-and-when-to-use-underscore)

Comment: (Sadly there doesn't seem to be any improvement on the answer there..)

Answer (score 5):

Either one is fine. I personally use hyphens (`-`) for command line options and underscores (`_`) in config files.