# MySQL server has gone away after Homebrew upgrade

Tags: php, mysql, homebrew

I just did a `brew upgrade` to PHP 7.2.8 and MySQL 8.0.12. After this, trying to connect to MySQL from a PHP script (from Bash) times out after 10 seconds (the default MySQL timeout value).

```
new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=foo;charset=utf8", "user", "pass");

[2006] MySQL server has gone away
```

Everything in my environment seems to be normal. I haven't changed anything else in my setup. Connecting to MySQL from Bash works fine. How do I regain MySQL access from PHP?

```
$ php -i | grep php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/7.2
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini

$ tail /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
pdo_mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

$ ls /tmp/mysql*
srwxrwxrwx  0 /tmp/mysql.sock
-rw-------  5 /tmp/mysql.sock.lock
srwxrwxrwx  0 /tmp/mysqlx.sock
-rw-------  6 /tmp/mysqlx.sock.lock

$ mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.
mysql> show variables like '%socket%';
+-----------------------------------------+------------------+
| mysqlx_socket                           | /tmp/mysqlx.sock |
| socket                                  | /tmp/mysql.sock  |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution: Add this to your MySQL configuration file (`my.cnf`):

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

[PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php):

> MySQL 8 defaults to `caching_sha2_password`, a plugin that is not recognized by the older PHP releases.
>   Instead, change it by setting `default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password` in `my.cnf`. The
>   `caching_sha2_password` plugin will be supported in a future PHP
>   release.

I hope this will save others some headache and time.

Comment: If it is not evident for you, like for me - you should put that configuration into your my.cnf, not php.ini.

Comment: It should be `default_authentication_plugin` (underscores, not dashes).

Comment: @John-MichaelL'Allier: You're mostly right. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736395/mysql-configuration-when-to-use-hyphen-and-when-to-use-underscore

Comment: @forthrin Thanks for the follow-up. I had thought the hyphens were _only_ for CLI options. I didn't realize they could be used in config files, too!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that doesn't require changing the default authentication configuration.

```
mysql> create user 'username'@'host' identified with mysql_native_password by 'password';
```

MySQL 8.0 References: [CREATE USER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html#create-user-overview) and [GRANT USER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html)

Once PHP is updated for SHA-256 authentication, you can 'alter user' to be identified with caching_sha2_password again.

Comment: I did that already (when switching to the previous versions of PHP and MySQL), but when switch to the current, I had to change the configuration. At least that's how it was on my machine.